# Start of Moving Average

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5, moving-average

Is there a pine script v5 that highlights a look back candle or vertical line of "x" moving average. For example, using a 50MA, the chart will highlight the 50th candle to signify the beginning of the 50MA.

```
//@version=5
indicator("Highlight 50th Candle", overlay = true)

// Define the candle index to highlight
highlightCandleIndex = 49  // 50th candle index is 49 (zero-based index)

// Check if the current bar index matches the highlightCandleIndex
highlightCondition = bar_index == highlightCandleIndex

// Determine the color of the highlight
highlightColor = color.new(color.yellow, 50)  // Yellow with 50% opacity

// Plot the highlight on the 50th candle
plotshape(series = highlightCondition, color = highlightColor, style = shape.triangleup, location = location.belowbar)

// Plot other indicators or data as needed
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do that. Use a label and the historical reference operator

```
indicator("My script", overlay = true)
var label start = na
ma = ta.sma(close,50)

if barstate.islast
    (start[1]).delete()
    start := label.new(bar_index[49], ma[49], style = label.style_xcross, size = size.tiny)

plot(ma)
```